# django form label in {% for %} statement

Tags: django, forms, for-loop

I want to wrap a  in a  label, but when the template was rendered, it didn't generate the right html, here is my code:

```
{% for item in studentinfo %}
                  <form action="" method="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
          <tr>

                  <td>{{ item.nickname|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.mobile|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.register_at|date:"Y-m-d"|default_if_none:"" }}</td>

            <td>{{ item.sales.first_name|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
            <td><strong class="red-text">{{ item.price|default_if_none:"" }}</strong></td>
            <td><strong class="red-text">{{ item.remaining|default_if_none:"" }}</strong></td>
            <td>{{ item.level|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
            <td>
                    {% if item.state %}
                    {{ setstudentform.state|default:item.state }}
                    {% else %}
                    {{ setstudentform.state }}
                    {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.source|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
            <td>
                    {% if item.feature %}
                    {{ setstudentform.feature|default:item.feature }}
                    {% else %}
                    {{ setstudentform.feature }}
                    {% endif %}
            </td>

          </tr>
                  </form>
          {% endfor %}
```

but it's generated html was like this:

```
<form method="" action=""></form>
<input type="hidden" value="8N1O4Oks4MmgN1ujanMZX0o2X5XGUMny" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
```

with nothing inside the `<form>`, why is that

Comment: What is `studentinfo`? Your question looks incomplete.

Comment: well, it's a context returned by view, doesn't matter here

Comment: Can you put here the output of that {% for %} but with {{ item }} instead of that big html form? that might help to debug

Comment: ok, I'll add it, it seems that in html you can't put a form in a table

Comment: you can put a form in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
  {% for item in studentinfo %}
  <tr>
      <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
```

The way you template is structured is not valid HTML.

Also, you don't need this:

```
{% if item.feature %}
   {{ setstudentform.feature|default:item.feature }}
{% else %}
   {{ setstudentform.feature }}
{% endif %}
```

Simply `{{ setstudentform.feature|default:item.feature }}` will do what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

The question is incomplete, I think -- we'd need to see what's around that `{% for %}` too, but I'll hazard a guess.

It looks like you're trying to interleave forms between table rows, which isn't likely legal in HTML and will cause the parsed DOM tree to look possibly something like your "generated HTML" example.

Did you check the HTML on the wire (using View Source (aside from IE, which when I last used it always output the parsed DOM tree as "source"), not a DOM inspector)? My educated guess is you'll find your HTML correct (or well, at least as you've templated it :) ) there.

So, in short, I don't think

```
<table>
  <form><tr>...</tr></form>
  <form><tr>...</tr></form>
</table>
```

isn't legal HTML.